# how to get first character in string with skip initial letters

Tags: python

Can anyone help on this. Tried multiple I am new to this python.
Need to get first character using python/pandas

`Stack_over_flow`

output should be : `Sof`

Appreciate your help on this. So that i can solve my issue. Can anyone help on this quick and efficient way?

Comment: Why `SVF` and not `SOF`?

Comment: split the string and take the first char of each split item

Comment: Homework without any self-work is a bad question

Comment: If you are looking for `SOF`, please try `in_str = "Stack_over_flow"

print(''.join(re.findall(r'(?:([a-z])[a-z]*\-*)+', in_str, re.IGNORECASE)).upper())`

Comment: @rioV8 I tried with split and '.join but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `split()` to split the string at underscore characters. Then concatenate the first character of each word.

```
string = 'Stack_over_flow'
print(''.join(word[0] for word in string.split('_'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If exptected result is `SOF`, please try

```
import re
in_str = "Stack_over_flow"  
print(''.join(re.findall(r'(?:([a-z])[a-z]*\-*)+', in_str, re.IGNORECASE)).upper())
```